# List all issues within a project

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, python-jira

How can I list all the issues within a project in Jira?

I am able to list all the projects, but not sure how to list all issues within a project.

This is how I list all the projects:

```
#/usr/bin/python
import jira.client
from jira.client import JIRA

options = {'server': 'http://jira.confluence.no' }
jira = JIRA(options, batch_auth=('admin', 'admin'))
project = jira.projects()
print project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.search_issues()`](https://pythonhosted.org/jira/#searching) method:

```
...
projects = jira.projects()
for project in projects:
    issues = jira.search_issues('project=' + project.key)
    for issue in issues:
        print issue
```

Comment: Thanks that did work. However its keep looping and printing the same values over again.

Comment: Did you double check that you wrote `print issue` and not `print issues`?

Comment: Ah! true. How can I list the creation and resolved time for each issue?

Comment: I guess you can access it using `issue.created`.

Comment: I double checked. I have `print issue` and not `print issues` what is the error?

Comment: Hm, it works fine for my test case, no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I had to put it outside the for-loop and then it worked. Thanks man. Howerver how can I sort the issues when printing? Like LB-1 then LB-2 on the next row etc?